# Calculate difference in years, months, days if every month has 30 days

Tags: java, groovy

Can't calculate difference between two dates in years, months, days. The problem is every month have 30 days, and every year have 365 days with no exceptions. There are a lot of topics here, but i haven't found any which can solve my problem or help with it. Every topic I found just solve problem calculating difference in normal way, which is simple.
How can I calculate such difference?

I'm using Java 7 (there is no opportunity to install joda time) and groovy 2.4.0.

Examples are:

```
date from    date to       y  m  d
2014-02-01 - 2015-02-01 => 1  0  1
2000-02-10 - 2003-01-18 => 2  11 9
2004-02-02 - 2004-06-24 => 0  4  23
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this in Groovy, not sure if it fits your requirements, but it gives the results in the question:

```
def dateMalarkey(Date from, Date to) {
    def val = [from, to].collect { d ->
        def cal = Calendar.instance
        cal.time = d
        [y: cal[Calendar.YEAR], m: cal[Calendar.MONTH], d: cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]]
    }.inject { p, n ->
        [y: Math.abs(p.y - n.y), m: Math.abs(p.m - n.m), d: Math.abs(p.d - n.d)  + 1]
    }
    val.days = val.y * 365 + val.m * 30 + val.d
    val
}

def inputs = [
    [from: '2014-02-01', to: '2015-02-01'],
    [from: '2000-02-10', to: '2003-01-18'],
    [from: '2004-02-02', to: '2004-06-24']
]

inputs.each { d ->
    println "$d.from - $d.to => " +
        dateMalarkey(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', d.from), Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', d.to))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your examples don't seem consistent. In the first case the end date is exclusive, on the other two it's inclusive. e.g. 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-01 should give 0d or 1d?
Assuming exclusive, it seems what you need can be done like this:
Given the fromDate as yearFrom, monthFrom and daysFrom and the toDate as yearTo, monthTo and daysTo:

```
days = -yearFrom*365-monthFrom*30-daysFrom+yearTo*365+monthTo*30+daysTo
```

will give you the difference in days, assuming a 365d year and a 30d month.
Then, the difference will be:

```
yearDifference = days/365 (as integer)
monthDifference = (days%365)/30
daysDifference = (days%365)%30
```

**Edit after comment**:
If you need it to be inclusive, as per the last two examples, just add one in "days":

```
days = -yearFrom*365-monthFrom*30-daysFrom+yearTo*365+monthTo*30+daysTo+1
```

Comment: seems to me it should be inclusive, and your example is exclusive, as I understand

Comment: But the results is different. I mean, that: 2004-02-02 - 2004-06-24 => 0  4  23 - is ok, but 2000-02-10 - 2003-01-18 returns 2 11 14 (should be 9 days)